# It does what it shouldn't with .equals statment JAVA

Tags: java, equals

I check if 2 objects(one new and one old from array list) match. If they do the program prints `"Company exists already!"` and if they don't match new object is added to a list.

The problem is that when I try to put same object(same values) twice it shows that it already exists like it should but when I enter completely new object (with different values) it still show that message but adds object to array list

```
if(companyList.size()!=0){
  for(i=0;i<companyList.size();i++){
    Company oldCom = companyList.get(i); 
    if(newUab.equals(oldCom)==true){

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Company exists already!");
      break;
    }
    else{
      companyList.add(newUab);
    }
  }

}
else{
  companyList.add(newUab);
}
```

I tried this `System.out.println(newUab.equals(oldCom));` and it always gives `true`
But I don't understand why when they are different, object is put in array list and when they are the same it doesn't though in both cases it prints the message?

Did I miss something or I spend to long looking at the code and can't see my mistakes anymore?

Edit: I put both classes because I lack of knowledge a bit on what method works(I think it should be UAB class method cause the object was of this class)
Company class(parent)

```
public class Company {
    public  String b;// boss
    public String n;// name
    public Company(String boss, String name){
    b=boss;
    n=name;
}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        int newHash;
        hash = 43 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.b);
        hash = 43 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.n);
        newHash=hash;
        return newHash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Company other = (Company) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.b, other.b)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.n, other.n)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

UAB class (child of company):

```
public class UAB extends Company {
    private  int w;//workers
    public UAB(String boss,String name,int workers){
        super(boss,name); 
        w=workers;

}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 17 * hash + this.w;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final UAB other = (UAB) obj;
        if (this.w != other.w) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: btw you don't have to write "==true" because equals will return true or false for you

Comment: Maybe you've made a mistake when implementing the equals method of Company. Could you provide the code for this method?

Comment: Would it be possible to also provide the code for Company and the Class for the newUab variable, especially the .equals() methods?

Comment: You should override the equals() method of the company so that you can say with guarantee that one is equal another. For example create a hashcode and compare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let's take a look at you existing *equals* method. You are using the Objects.equals method, which is a bit odd because it simply calls *firstArgument*.equals(*secondArgument*), after checking for nullity, but you already checked it somewhat.

What you should rather do :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ( ! obj instanceof Company ) {
        return false;
    }

    Company other = (Company) obj;

    return this.b.equals(other.b) && this.n.equals(other.n);
}
```

As others have noted, you should rather use the contains method of the List interface rather than implement your own. Furthermore, you should maybe consider using a Set if the order of the objects is not important. In Sets, you cannot have duplicates and adding will simply fail (return false) if you try to add an "equal" element.

Also, in your UAB class, you also need to check the *b* and *n* parameters. You can call the parent *equals* method using the "super" keyword...

Another advice : Lookup the code in the java source! Go take a look at what is done in ArrayList and other classes. You'll see how they implement the contains method, and you can use that as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I am using equals as a learning task and its the only way I have thought to make equals meaningful in my program but I guess I don't understand them enough to use them(back to the tutorials:D)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you do [ArrayList#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to check for whether your object exists or not?

And hope you are overriding `equals` to compare your object on basis of custom parameter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

your probelm is here >>

```
else{
    companyList.add(newUab);
}
```

as you are saying for new object it prints "Company exists already!"
and still adding it, then the execution of adding to list would be at above line

Comment: That's just one of the problems, OP said that when he performs equals it always returns true and it shouldn't

Comment: it always return true that might be because they are equal and We just can hope that he overrided the equals method. And yes he equals always boolean so he should not test with true

Comment: But how? first else is with the if statement which checks if list is empty, if it is it adds new object second else is with if statement which checks if the object is already in the list. If if statement is true it can't do else statement?

Answer (score 1):

If the object does not match the first in the list, it gets added to the array. You cannot add to the array until you have compared against every object in the list. A better solution would likely be to call list.[contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)(newUab) rather than iterating over the list yourself and calling .equals.

Comment: I need to use hashcode and .equals for this task :(

Comment: Eclipse will generate hashcode and equals implementations that are pretty decent. If that is not an option, apache commons has utilities for implementing both methods.   http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html   http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html